# Telerik RadGrid : Raise an event in Form when the Form Window is Maximized

Tags: telerik, radgridview

I have a `RadgridView` along with a button in a `Form` `Window`.When the button is clicked , it shows some hidden rows in `RadGridView`.

I want the hidden rows to be showed when the Form window is maximized.
I am trying something like this in `Form_Activated` method:

```
If Me.WindowState=2 Then
    button1.PerformClick()
```

upon Debugging,  I can see that the method that handles click event executes but nothing is being done in the Form Window i.e the columns are not showing up.
Am I missing something? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to handle the `WindowStateChanged` event, see https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radwindow/features/states

In that event you will need to check the `WindowState` of your `Window` object. Since you have not specified which class is the one where you handle the event, the `Me` might be referring to something different from your window. For `WindowStateChanged` the sender contains the `RadWindow`. You will need to debug and figure out which member of the sender is the `RadWindow`. It may be the sender itself. You will need to refer `WindowState` through the sender.

Also, I recommend that you could avoid triggering clicks in order to change UI properties. You could just have a function which handles every change necessary when the window is maximalized and call that instead of doing a click.

As explained in the comment section, this logic needs to be handled in the `Resize` event.

Comment: Thanks for the response , Lajos. I am writing this code in the window's Activated event handling method, So Me refers to the Form Window.
So should I create a method that handles WindowStateChanged event of the Window?
I am writing in VB.net and it says that event WindowSateChanged does not exist.

Comment: @schwifty it has been a long while since I last worked with Telerik controls. Please let me know about the class name of your window. Is it RadWindow?

Comment: Window is System.Windows.Forms.Form which contains button and RadGridView Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView

Comment: Lajos, I figured it out . I have to handle Resize event of the Form.
Really appreciate the help.